# Display data on form and update form asynchronously

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-ajax

What is the best way to approaching this? I have a text box where Teachers enter Student ID and I want to display student information based on the id entered. Once the student info is displayed, I have a drop down list which populates with a list which lists all the classes that student is enrolled in. Once a course is selected from that drop down list I want to display students progress on the form in a particular section on the form. How can I approach this? Here is What I have so far:

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Student.Models;


namespace Student.Controllers
{
    public class StudentFormController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /StudentForm/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("StudentForm");
        }

        public ActionResult DisplayStudentDetails(string StudentId)
        {
            StudentDataContext db = new StudentDataContext();
            var StudentName = (from p in db.vwStudent.Where(a => a.StudentID == StudentId)
                             group p by p.StudentName into g
                             select g.Key).FirstOrDefault();

            var StudentClassList = (from p in db.vwStudent.Where(a => a.StudentID ==          StudentId)
                             group p by p.ClassID into g
                             select g.Key).ToList();

            ViewData["StudentName"] = StudentName;
            ViewData["StudentClassList "] = StudentClassList ;

            return View("StudentForm");

        }

        public ActionResult DisplayClassDetails(string StudentId, string ClassId)
        {
            StudentDataContext db = new StudentDataContext();
            ViewData.Model = (from p in db.vwStudentProgress.Where(a => a.StudentID == StudentId && a.ClassID == ClassId);

            return View("LPForm");

        }

    }
}
```

View(Form):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Student Form
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<form id="form2" method="get" action="/StudentForm/DisplayStudentDetails/" runat="server">
    <div style="text-align: left; height: 202px;">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>                
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        Student Id:<input type="text" name="id" value="<%=HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["StudentId"]%>" /><br />                    
        Student Name:<input type="text" name="StudentName" value="<%=ViewData["ShortName"]%>" /><br />
        Classes Enrolled in:
        <select name="Classes">
            <%if (ViewData["Classes"] != null)
            {%>               
            <% foreach (int? Classes in (List<int?>)ViewData["Classes"])
            {%>                                
            <option><%=Classes%></option>                                
            <%}%>               
            <%}%>                   
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
    <input type="submit" value="Display Student Details"/>
</div>
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Basically you are asking to make (a part of) your application... Anyway, what is the problem you are exactly struggling with? What is it that you don't understand, that you have problems with? (And don't say "to make this".)

Comment: @Styxxy "What is the best way to approaching this" is my intention. NO Intention to let you write my code. "Anyway" Just want to know what the best way to approaching this. I have multiple sections on the form which needs to be updated asynchronously. Some sections will be dependent on others some independent. Also, there couple sections which have one to many relationships. i.e. Pulling data from db and showing on form and updating/inserting the data.

Comment: As you say yourself, it needs to be done asynchronously. First thing that pop ups in my head is AJAX. You can do requests to actions in your controllers (with certain parameters) and let them return back a (partial) view. I suggest you to look into AJAX, as it is (definitely) what you look for. If you can't figure out the flow, you can post it as a question (but dumping this much code is not very helpful nor makes the question clear).

Comment: Isn't this an MVC app? Why are you using update panels?

Comment: @Mark yes, it is an MVC app. What else would I use for asynchronous updates?

Comment: My blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx does exactly this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to approaching this?

Simple answer is AJAX. Don't try to use update panels in an ASP.NET MVC application. Use jquery to male ajax calls and update portions of your page.

> Once a course is selected from that drop down list I want to display
>   students progress on the form in a particular section on the form. How
>   can I approach this?

Basically you should bind to the change event of the dropdown through jquery and call an action that returns a partial view.

Use html helpers to create textboxes, form and other stuff and avoid using the html elements directly.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What are the benefits of using jquery as compared to update panels? and same with html helpers Vs. using elements directly?

Comment: @Mark is correct. See my blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx